# Mule CE runtime not listening on port 80

Tags: runtime, mule, windows-ce

I've installed Mule CE runtime on an AWS EC2 Lynx server and dropped my Anypoint Studio project into into the app folder, Mule starts fine and says my app is deployed but it appears Mule is not listening on port 80 as expected, what am I missing?

Comment: have you configured your application to listen to port 80.  Mule CE runtime default port is not 80.

Answer (score 0):

Mule CE runtime default port is not 80. Hope you have configured port 80 for mule soft CE.
For port configuration you can check configuration [Here.](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.7/setting-up-mmc-mule-esb-communications)

To check which port is being used by mule CE :

On Unix machine :  `netstat -tulpn | grep <port>` (i.e 80 in your case, check for 7777 as well.)

On Windows machine :

1. Open `Run` prompt on Windows
2. Type `perfmon /res` ,press `OK`
3. On `Resource Monitor`, on `Network` tab, search for the port under `Listening Ports`

Answer (score 0):

Great I can see port 80 & 8081 in use by Java now,  my issue was two fold I was dropping my project folder onto apps once I changed to drop the Anypoint zip deployment file I saw a Java version error, rebuilt on 1.7, redeployed and it's working, thanks for your help

Comment: @sky-high, if the answer was useful you should at least upvote it - that's how SO works :-)